# How do I get all of my divs to shrink in height as the width of the viewport changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get all of my divs to shrink in height as the width of the viewport changes?

Example: https://jenis.com/

When you reduce the width of this website, the heights of the divs reduce in height.

Comment: try adding css height property with percentage %.

Comment: Hope you are talking about responsive sites. Use `media queries` to create a responsive contents in page

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Well yea, but if you look at the site, you will notice the heights of the divs continue to get smaller as the width of the viewport gets smaller. With the media queries, the heights of the divs will only get smaller at the breakpoint.

Comment: then ofcourse as @AbhishekPachal suggested use `%` or `vw`, `vh` or `vmin` See **[here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thanks... "vw" works

Comment: Anytime!! But if you see `vmin` it works for both `height` and `width`

Answer (score 0):

You use percentage based CSS. For the main image, they are using the following tag to scale the background to the browser viewport:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

100% means the element's content area will equal exactly the explicit width of its parent, provided its parent has an explicit width.

Comment: Yes, but as you make the viewport smaller, the height of the background gets smaller as well. Not just the width. Like, the div keeps its proportions.

Comment: It's the same concept. They are using percentages to calculate it based on the viewport. For that example, the main leaderboard div has `padding-bottom: 66.6666%`, which is shrinking as the viewport gets smaller, thus reducing the padding beneath the leaderboard.

Comment: Thanks, ill give that a try. I figured out that "vw" works really well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` and `vw` units to achieve this. 'vw' is the viewport width and 'vh` stands for viewport height.

If you give `height:50vw`, the height of div will be directly proportional to the viewport width.

Comment: Its supported in **IE>10**

Comment: IE9+ it supports. IE8 is not supported.